Strange gRPC Issue on iOS for Blazor MAUI Hybrid
We are using gRPC in our app and it works great, now suddenly we got the error below on iOS, the exact same code works great on Android and Windows. The error:
TypeInitialization_Type, DefaultProxyCache`1
   at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Configuration.ClientFactory.DefaultClientFactory.CreateClient[IReceiversService](CallInvoker channel)
   at MyApp.App.MauiProgram.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CreateMauiApp>b__7(IServiceProvider services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceIdentifier, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ServiceAccessor, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].GetOrAdd(ServiceIdentifier , Func`2 )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreatePropertyInjector>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider , Type , IComponentRenderMode , Nullable`1 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] , Int32 , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer , RenderBatchBuilder , Int32 , ArrayRange`1 , ArrayRange`1 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder , RenderFragment , Exception& )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()

I just cannot figure out what is wrong and how to fix this. I have tried to upgrading all NuGet packages we have related to gRPC:
 <PackageReference Include="protobuf-net.Grpc" Version="1.1.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.28.0-rc1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.65.0-pre1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client.Web" Version="2.65.0-pre1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.65.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>

But to no avail and completely stuck on how to troubleshoot this. As mentioned, its only iOS this is an issue and it worked previously. We are using .NET 8.0.303 and compiling using AOT.

It's going to be difficult for others to diagnose this with only a stacktrace. Evidently something has changed; it would be prudent to identify that|those changes. Does the issue occur always? reproducibly? Unless this is already known to e.g. Microsoft, it would be prudent to find a minimal repro of the issue presumably it's with gRPC. Either start removing chunks of your app until the issue disappears or, start from a known working sample and add until the issue recurs.

I do not see that we introduced anything new rather than some .NET nuget packages update from 8.0.6 to 8.0.7 and .WebView.Maui and .Maui.Controls to 8.0.70 instead of 8.0.40 but I have tried reverting those upgrades as well and still getting the error above. I have been removing chunks of code step-by-step to narrow down what is wrong and so far only found that yeah if I essentially remove my gRPC services then it works but nothing else. I also don't understand what the error message actually mean. I tried removing that particular service but then it complains on my other gRPC service instead.

And worse is that it works perfect in the Browser, Android and Windows, the gRPC code is unchanged so I do not see that we made some conceptual mistake in the code. But rather some iOS issue because its only in iOS we get this error.

Yes, I think it's definitive that iOS is part of the issue but it's possible the error exists on other platforms but has (not yet) surfaced. Given your  assertion that it was working and is now not working, something must have changed. It's turtles all the way down, but iOS may have introduced the breaking change too. The only way you can solve this is either to find a minimal repro that you can show to that code's developers or hope that someone has done this for you and already identified the issue. Are your tracking the repos of these projects for relevant issues?

After many hours of trying out different things and looking through the logs I noticed that the MAUI package microsoft.net.sdk.ios had been updated some weeks ago. There seems to be a bug in it (version 17.2.8078) that causes this issue. Related issue here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20910
When I specified exact version the same way they did it now works again.
